# Trimming a nvarchar param in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a stored procedure that sends a string to one of my parameters

```
@deliveryName [nvarchar](255)
```

Sometimes the delivery name can be "Delivery example 1" and sometimes it can be "Delivery method - Delivery example 1", it could also be "something else - Delivery example 1"

This cant be edited before it hits the stored procedure, is there a safe way to trim everything before the first "-" purely in sql server MSSQL? I say is there a safe way in the case that there are multiple "-" in the delivery name. for example "Delivery method - Delivery example - 2" i would just want it to output "Delivery example - 2"

Everywhere ive looked so far is saying to use a case when (something like this)

```
CASE
    WHEN str LIKE ',%,' THEN SUBSTRING(str, 2, LEN(str)-2)
    WHEN str LIKE ',%'  THEN RIGHT(str, LEN(str)-1)
    WHEN str LIKE '%,'  THEN LEFT(str, LEN(str)-1)
    ELSE str
END
```

for every eventuality but there are always new methods daily so this would be hard to keep up with.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: You can use string functions like - 
SELECT LTRIM(RIGHT(@deliveryName, LEN(@deliveryName) - CHARINDEX('-',@deliveryName)))
Alternatively you can also use SUBSTRING

Comment: @SivaL SELECT TRIM( '-' FROM  ' Delivery method - Delivery example - 2') AS Result; wouldn't work though as i only want to discard before the first -

Comment: @GazSmith, In this example, CHARINDEX plays major role in finding position of the first "-" and discards anything before that with the help of RIGHT function. LTRIM is only to remove leading spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it just needs a `SUBSTRING` with a `CHARINDEX` or `PATINDEX` to get the position of the first dash.

**Test snippet**

> ```
> declare @deliveryName nvarchar(255);
> set @deliveryName = 'Delivery method - Delivery example - 2';
>
> set @deliveryName = ltrim(substring(@deliveryName, charindex('-', @deliveryName)+1, len(@deliveryName)));
>
> select @deliveryName as deliveryName;
> ```

> | deliveryName |
> | --- |
> | Delivery example - 2 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=672742fc1a76421a34a3f9da90c600ce)*

Answer (score 0):

You could append a '-' to your `DeliveryName` variable for names that don't have a '-', get the index of first occurence of '-' and get the string to right of that index

```
SELECT RIGHT(DeliveryName, CHARINDEX('-', DeliveryName+'-')+2) FROM #Temp

CREATE TABLE #Temp ( DeliveryName NVARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('Delivery example-1')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('Delivery method - Delivery example 1 ')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES (' something else - Delivery example 1')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES (' Delivery method - Delivery example - 2')

SELECT RIGHT(DeliveryName, CHARINDEX('-', DeliveryName+'-')+2) FROM #Temp

output
--------------------------------------------------------
(No column name)
Delivery example 1
Delivery example 1 
Delivery example 1 
Delivery example - 2
Delivery example-1
```